# positive correlation but p value is 0.152

Tags: self-study, correlation, p-value

[image][image]I have a positive correlation but my p-value is 0.152 am I being stupid or can any help it's kinda urgent

Comment: Can we see the data?

Comment: What are your null and alternative hypotheses? What are you using to test your hypothesis?

Comment: ive added it to the post and i dont have a hypothesis its just a scatter graph for part of an assignment

Comment: i have like 8 scatter graphs and they all make sense i think other than that one

Comment: Well what have you attempted in your homework problem? Please add the self-study tag and read how we handle homework problems on this stack.

Comment: Can you post the results of the linear regression?

Comment: ive added it to the post

Comment: What is the question? Is a correlation of 0.39 meaningful to you or not? Should we answer this without background knowledge?

Comment: Without any real context, here is an answer that I think you are after. The (lack of) significance of the coefficient is related to the weak positive correlation. The variables do not show a statistically significant relationship between the variables and the independent variable cannot reliably predict the dependent variable. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/output/regression-analysis/

Comment: I agree with @SextusEmpiricus. You  don't seem to have asked a question.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the p-value is used to asses the significance of, for example, a correlation. It "evaluates" whether your data provides enough evidence to consider that the correlation is greater than zero. 
Two things have an effect on the p-value. One is the **effect size**, how large your correlation is. Larger correlations provide a smaller p-value. 
But also your **sample size** has an effect. Larger sample sizes lead also to smaller sample sizes.

Finding a large correlation when asking 5 people can just happen by chance, but if you ask 5000 people it is unlikely that the correlation just happened by chance. At least that is the theory.

Together sample size and effect size can be used to calculate the **power**, which measures how likely is is that you are going to find a significant effect given your sample size and effect size.

In you case you most likely do not have enough power, because your sample size is so small. That is why you can find a moderate correlation, but you did not ask enough people to be sure that it is not due to random noise in the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just 1 independent variable then the beta coefficient of the standardized independent variable is just its correlation with the dependent variable, which you can see matches with your correlations. So nothing has gone wrong with the software or what you clicked if you are worried about that.

If you take your unstandardized beta coefficient and divide it by your standard error you get your test statistic, and you can look that up to get your p value, which is the probability that you would observe that beta coefficient (the effect size) *IF* the null hypothesis is true. With p=0.152, that doesn't seem too unlikely so you don't have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis as being untrue.

Basically, a good analogy is to look at the standard error *like* it's a measure of uncertainty in your estimated difference. And the Wald T test is a ratio between how big the difference you observed/estimated VS how unsure you are of it. In your context, 0.003 might be quite big of an observed difference, and indeed standardizing it to get a correlation shows it's 0.389 which doesn't seem insignificant. But when you compare it to how unsure you are of it (0.003 vs 0.002), it's actually not that big, so you can't reject the null hypothesis.